# Factory for lists

Tags: c#, list, factory

My apologies if this looks very much like a similar question I asked a few weeks back; I am learning.

I have a function that should return a List of objects - somewhat like a Factory. In the example below I have two classes Truck and Car who both inherit from the superclass Vehicle. The function does not work, but it should show what I want to accomplish.

EDIT: Forgot to say HOW it did not work. Well, the function creates a List of, for example, Trucks, but cannot return it since the return value must be a List of *Vehicle*. I do not know how to convert the created list or even if it *can* be converted.

Obviously I am primarily asking for advice how to get the damned thing to work! But I would also appreciate any ideas on how to get it more scalable - to have a "case" statement for every possible Vehicle class does not make me happy.

The v.Populate function is just there to fill the object with data from the DataReader. Should not affect the problem at hand.

Calling the function, in this instance I want a List with Truck objects:  **return PopulateList("Truck", gc);**

```
private List<Vehicle> PopulateList(String type, GenericConnection gc)
{
    Vehicle v;
    var ret = new List<Vehicle>();
    var r = gc.ExecuteReader();
    while (r.Read())
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case "Truck":
                v = new Truck();
                break;
            case "Car":
                v = new Car();
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Unknown Vehicle: " + type, "type");
        }
        v.Populate(r);
        ret.Add(v);
    }
    r.Close();
    return ret;
}
```

For clarity, here is a copy of the same function but now all non-essential code (mostly concerning the DataReader) is stripped away. The return value should be a List with exactly one empty object in it.

```
private List<Vehicle> PopulateList(String type)
{
    Vehicle v;
    var ret = new List<Vehicle>();
    switch (type)
    {
        case "Truck":
            v = new Truck();
        case "Car":
            v = new Car();
        }
    }
    ret.Add(v);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: What is not working with your code? At first glance it looks as if it should work.

Comment: Where/how are you calling the method?

Comment: Try to avoid statements like 'it does not work' . Describe the results and/or exceptions instead.

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future... VS 2017 supports a case statement on Type (called Pattern Matching) so you can switch(myVehicle) { case CommercialVehicle vehicle when vehicle.Wheels > 6: DoCode and so one. Beware that the order of the cases is now important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use generics:

```
public interface IPopulate {
   void Populate( DbDataReader dataReader );
}

....
private List<T> PopulateList<T>( GenericConnection gc )
    where T : IPopulate, new()
{
    T v;
    var ret = new List<T>();
    var r = gc.ExecuteReader();
    while (r.Read())
    {
        v = new T();
        v.Populate(r);
        ret.Add(v);
    }
    r.Close();
    return ret;
}
```

You'd call it like

```
PopulateList<Truck>( connection );
PopulateList<Car>( connection );
```

Comment: Thank you, Wiktor. This is what I needed. Just a detail: the signature should end "... where T : IPopulate, new()"

Answer (score 0):

You can create generic method:

```
private List<Vehicle> PopulateList<T>() where T: Vehicle
    {
        Vehicle v = new T();
        var ret = new List<Vehicle>();
        // main logic
        ret.Add(v);
        return ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a generic method:

```
public T CreateInstance<T>() where T : Vehicle, new()
{
    var obj = new T();
    return obj;
}
```

Usage:

```
var truck = CreateInstance<Truck>();
var car = CreateInstance<Car>();
```